# Sometimes when I click AngularJS links, the page reloads

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a single-page app that has several views. On one view, I list all the `order`s, on another page, I modify those `order`s. I want to be able to go between the two pages without needing to save any data to a database. 
On my development box, this works well. I just save the `orders` on `$window` and when I load the details page, I look through `window.orders` for it. Great. However, when deployed, all my links act like they link to a new page... so the page reloads. This means that when I try to link from my main list page to my details page, the details page doesn't get access to anything on `window`. Isn't the whole point of a single page app that it doesn't reload the page when changing views? How do I get my links to not load a new page? they're all in the format of `<a href="#!/<view>">text</a>`.

So here's part of my orders-list.template.html:

```
<table class="table-bordered" id="TheTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Part #</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Job #</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th ng-repeat="day in days" class="td-nowrap">{{day}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:'DueDate'">
        <th><a href="#!/orders/{{order.ID}}">{{order.PartNumber}}</a></th>
        <td>{{order.Customer}}</td>
        <td class="td-nowrap">{{order.JobNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{order.DueDate|date:'shortDate'}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="day in days">
            <input type="number" style="width:60px;" ng-model="order.Weeks[day].Pieces" ng-change="calculateHoursOfWork();"/>
            {{(order | runTimePlusSetupPlusEfficiency:options:order.Weeks[day].Pieces) | number:3}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the part number is a link to `#!/orders/{{order.ID}}`. I was under the impression this link wouldn't reload the web page.

This is in my main script:

```
            $routeProvider.
                when("/orders", {
                    template: "<orders-list></orders-list>"
                }).
                when("/orders/:orderId", {
                    template: "<order-detail></order-detail>"
                }).
                when("/options", {
                    template: "<options></options>"
                }).
                when("/printable", {
                    template: "<orders-printable></orders-printable>"
                }).
                otherwise("/orders");
```

So it should be clear that `/orders` refers to my ordersDetail component. Here's part of it:

```
angular.module("orderDetail").component("orderDetail", {
    templateUrl: "AngularModules/order-detail/order-detail.template.html",
    controller: ['$routeParams', "$http", "$window", function OrderDetailController($routeParams, $http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.TotalNonSetupRunTime = 0.0;
        self.options = $window.options;

        self.order = null;
        $.each($window.orders, function (idx, elem) {
            if (elem.ID == $routeParams.orderId) {
                self.order = elem;
            }
        });
        if (self.order === null) {
            var orderID = null;
            if ($routeParams.hasOwnProperty('orderId')) {
                orderID = $routeParams.orderId;
            }
            var windowOrders = "undefined";
            if ($window.hasOwnProperty('orders')) {
                windowOrders = $window.orders.length;
            }
            alert("couldn't find order " + orderID + " among " + windowOrders + " orders! try going back and selecting again.");
        }
    }]
});
```

because the page is getting reloaded, I'm seeing `windowOrders` as `undefined`. Is there some setting in IIS I could change to make links to `#<something>` not reload the page (as expected)? or do I have to do something on the angularJS side?

Confounding it further... I did find this: [hash link reloads page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128575/hash-link-reloads-page) and apparently having a `<base>` directive screws with this? is there an angular-safe way to do this? I don't think it would make sense to get rid of that directive. I'm actually writing this on an asp.net-MVC page, so I have

```
<base ng-href="@Url.HttpRouteUrl("Default", new { }).Replace("?httproute=True", "")" />
```

in my _Layout.cshtml page. This way when it gets deployed (to `http://<server>/<app>/`) it works as well as when I'm debugging (on `locahost:<some port>/`).

Comment: To be sure that your page is reloading, have you tried to put any console trace in the .run method of the main module?

Comment: About your question about the fragment, the answer is no, the url fragment is only processed by the client, you can see this: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-4

Comment: @Kalamarico I put `Page loaded at @DateTime.Now` in my index page, it was showing a new time. I'm pretty sure the page is reloading.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey Can you try `<a href="#/orders/{{order.ID}}">` instead of `<a href="#!/orders/{{order.ID}}">` what is the reason for using exclamation?